# Adding multiple "Disabled Cell" Behaviors to Behavior Manager

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

In a single GridControl I need to enable/disable 2 separately cells, on different conditions.

For example: If cellA is true, then I want to disable cellB (I already have this one working), but if cellD is true, then I want to disable cellE.

I've added a Disabled Cell Behavior:

[image]

But I need to add another one (because it's a different expression). But the option to add a new Disabled Cell Behavior is no longer there:

[image]

I also tried adding a different Behavior Manager, but the button to add a Behavior is fully disabled:

[image]

Is there something I could do in this case?

Comment: I've found a *workaround*. While DevExpress interface prevents you from adding the Behavior, doesn't mean you can't add it yourself **manually**. By going to the .Designer.cs and duplicating a `AppearanceObject`, a `DisabledCellEvents`, adding the events to `.SetBehaviors` and setting the callback for the `ProcessingCell` seems to work. Now this is probably **not officially supported** and there might be better options out there, but it does work. I'll wait some time before posting this as a answer.

Comment: Please, note that changing the `*.Designer.cs` files is an undocumented and incorrect way of accomplishing your task and there is a public (and documented) one. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach all the required behaviors in Code using public and documented way - the `behaviorManager.Attach<TBehavior>` method:

```
BehaviorManager behaviorManager1 = new BehaviorManager(this.components);

//Use the Attach method to assign Behavior to a control in code.
behaviorManager1.Attach<DragDropBehavior>(gridView1, behavior => {
    behavior.Properties.AllowDrop = true;
    behavior.Properties.InsertIndicatorVisible = true;
    behavior.Properties.PreviewVisible = true;
    behavior.DragDrop += Behavior_DragDropToGrid1;
});
```

Take a look at the [Attach Behavior to a Control in Code](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/117235/common-features/behaviors#attach-behavior-to-a-control-in-code) documentation section related to this approach.

Please also review the [Drag-and-Drop Behavior](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/118656/common-features/behaviors/drag-and-drop-behavior) help article and the special [How to Attach the Drag-and-Drop Behavior to a Control in Code](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/118656/common-features/behaviors/drag-and-drop-behavior#how-to-attach-the-drag-and-drop-behavior-to-a-control-in-code) section.